# C# Paint event for disabled button (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a weird problem. I'm trying to edit the paint event for disabled button but because of some reason when I try to use text from *sender* to display, the text is not rendered (*string buttonTextCopy*). If I create a hard coded variable (*string test*) which is the same string as button text then it's working fine. It doesn’t matter if I use button controller or IconButton controller, the result is the same. Can someone help me understand what's going on?

Also I have one more question. With my hard coded variable I noticed that position of my text and icon is different after I overwrite the event. Is there any way to copy the old *paint event* text and icon position and pass it to the new one?

```
private void currentFormButton_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = (sender as IconButton);
        btn.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(243, 239, 224);
        btn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(108, 16, 12);
    }

    private void currentFormButton_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        IconButton btn = (IconButton)sender;
        string buttonTextCopy = btn.Text.ToString();
        // make sure Text is not also written on button
        string test = "General Settings";
        btn.Text = string.Empty;
        // render the text onto the button
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, test, btn.Font, e.ClipRectangle, btn.ForeColor);

    }
```

My goal is to make the button disabled, where only backcolor is changed.
[image]

Comment: You set `string buttonTextCopy = btn.Text.ToString();`, then `btn.Text = string.Empty;`. The next time the control is invalidated, `buttonTextCopy` will of course be set to an empty string. Also, you're not considering the string placement in any way. There's code missing here: you're probably receiving a Graphics object already modified by code in a custom control. `e.ClipRectangle` is probably not the correct measure, but it depends on the content of the PaintEventArgs object you're receiving. Some more details on what we're looking at here wouldn't hurt.

Comment: You set `btn.Text = string.Empty;` Next time the button is rendered the text is already set to `string.Empty;`. Please keep in mind that paint methods are called many times. For example if you switch between visual studio and the form or the form is moved or otherwise invalidated.

Comment: e.ClipRectangle does not do what you think it does.  Use btn.ClientRectangle instead.

Comment: @Jimi I have *MainForm* which has a left panel buttons. When button is pressed the new form is open in the middle panel of that form. The button controller is passed into child form and make the button disabled. So I'm trying to change behaviour of paint event when child form is active. When I set break point on line `TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, buttonTextCopy, btn.Font, e.ClipRectangle, btn.ForeColor);` I can see that variable `buttonTextCopy` still has a correct value but  text rendered is empty.